# node.js socket.io - track requested url

Tags: node.js, url, express, socket.io

I'm testing to give out requested URLs, but when I try:

```
http://localhost:4000/foo
```

the Browser says: Cannot GET /foo

My server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http .createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var url = require('url');





server.listen(4000);

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
 console.log("currentpathname: "+pathname);
});
```

I want to get out "foo" for:

```
 http://localhost:4000/foo
```

Comment: change `app.get('/', . . .` to `app.get('*', . . .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express only handles paths you tell it to handle, all other paths it returns 404s with messages like `Cannot GET /foo`

`app.get('/'` only handles `'/'` to handle all paths you need to use `app.get'*'`

As a note the canonical

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

is equivalent to

```
express().all('*', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

To get a feel of how things work I recommend toying with just the core http module for a bit.